# Wordpress Installation realated query

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to upload wordpress site created by me. I think I have two options in installing wordpress

1. Install wordpress by clicking "install wordpress" icon in cpanel.
2. Download wordpress files from wordpress site, then upload those files to my hosting site.

I feel second method is simple. I think second method requres some 200 mb space. I'm ok with that. Is there any problem in that method?? Experts please provides some advice. I need to upload multiple sites, so I think using webhosting company wordpress option will be very difficult to configure. Also i'm planning to upload wordpress files for individual websites.

Answer (score 0):

Yes right. You already created wordpress project on local machine then you don't need to install wordpress from cPanel. What you need to do is, upload your whole folder and change path inside database, specially in wp_options.

In other case you must install wordpress from cPanel if you want to start your project direct on live (without creating setup on local machine). Sorry if i am wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

yes if you have already created project then only move files and database on server.
In Database you have to change url localhost to your domain.

If you create new project then you are doing as you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for your option NO : 2

https://themeskingdom.com/knowledge-base/how-to-migrate-wordpress-from-localhost-to-live-server/